# How to control exact size of tight figure with subplots in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I made this piece of code to generate a grid of subplots with a specific figure size specified in inches.
Line 12 specifies the figure width (about 150mm).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

def img(fig,grid):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(grid)
    plot = ax.pcolormesh(np.random.random((10,10)), vmin=0, vmax=1)
    return ax,plot

rows = 3
cols = 4 
x_inches = 5.905            # ~150mm
y_inches = x_inches*(rows/cols)
dpi = 96

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize = (x_inches,y_inches), dpi = dpi)
layout = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols = cols, nrows = rows, figure = fig)

for m in range(rows):
    for n in range(cols):
        img(fig,layout[m,n])

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.4, wspace = 0.4)    
plt.savefig('example.pdf', dpi = dpi, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches = 0)
plt.show()`
```

The code generates a .pdf file with the vector figure inside:

[image]

However, when I look into the document properties of the .pdf file, it says that the figure is 125.4 x 93.9 mm

By changing line 24 to: `plt.savefig('example.pdf', dpi = dpi, pad_inches = 0)`

the resulting figure is:

[image]

Im this case, the figure have the dimensions I set, however without the tight aspect.

How could I generate a figure with specified size and tight boxes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use constrained_layout or tight_layout and dont use bbox_inches=tight.

Comment: Thank you. It solves partially the problem. Now I can't control the distances between the graphs ):

Comment: Please read the constrained layout guide for the space and pad numbers